# More than One Servlet in a Project?

Tags: html, mysql, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm trying to make a simple input registration and login page. The first servlet for the Login works perfectly well, but the second servlet for registration just doesn't seem to connect. Can you connect 2 servlets to 2 different forms?

```
<form name="login" method="Post" action="HomeServlet">


<form name="login" method="post" action="RegisterServlet">
```

web.xml files:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>HomeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Please share a minimal but _complete_ set of example code so that we can reproduce your problem. Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: Looks like a kind of assignment - would request you to go through the basics, you can find out good examples here. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm